# Expose ports on a Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, port, docker-swarm, infrastructure, swarm

Is it possible to "expose" ports in a docker Swarm?

Something similar to the expose instruction in the docker-compose, which differently from "ports" does not expose the ports externally to the network.

If it's not possible, why?

Answer (score 2):

[Expose is documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). Any two containers can communicate between each other on ports the containers are using as long as they share a docker network. This is the same whether it's a bridge or overlay network (assuming the host is correctly configured to support overlay networks).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it does the same as expose if you specify *target* and *published* with the same port

`docker service create --publish target=8080,published=8080 ...`